# How to store a value and re-use it in the same xml file?

Tags: xml

I have a autoinst.xml which will be used during the installation of the system to setup arp bonding, it is configured to take input from user with respect to ip, gateway and netmask as below

```
        <path>networking,dns,hostname</path>
        <title>INS Server Network Settings</title>
        <question>Enter Hostname</question>
        <stage>cont</stage>
        <default></default>
    </ask>

    <ask>
        <dialog config:type="integer">2</dialog>
        <element config:type="integer">2</element>
        <path>networking,interfaces,0,ipaddr</path>
        <title>INS Server Network Settings</title>
        <question>Enter the server IP address:</question>
        <stage>cont</stage>
        <default>1.2.3.4</default>
    </ask>

    <ask>
    <dialog config:type="integer">2</dialog>
        <element config:type="integer">3</element>
        <path>networking,interfaces,0,netmask</path>
        <question>Enter the server netmask:</question>
        <stage>cont</stage>
        <default>255.255.255.0</default>
    </ask>

    <ask>
        <dialog config:type="integer">2</dialog>
        <element config:type="integer">4</element>
        <path>networking,routing,routes,0,gateway</path>
        <question>Enter the server default gateway:</question>
        <stage>cont</stage>
        <default>1.2.3.1</default>
```

Here I want to use the value provided in "Gateway" section above to be used below. Suppose user provides 192.168.10.100 as gateway above it should be stored in a variable and I can place the variable name inside arp_ip_target below so that the default gateway is used as the target. But I am not sure how can I do this?

```
<interfaces config:type="list">
       <interface>
          <device>bond0</device>
          <startmode>onboot</startmode>
          <bonding_master>yes</bonding_master>
          <bonding_module_opts>arp_interval=1000 arp_ip_target="**gateway**" mode=1 arp_validate=all</bonding_module_opts>
          <bonding_slave0>eth0</bonding_slave0>
          <bonding_slave1>eth1</bonding_slave1>
          <ipaddr></ipaddr>
          <netmask></netmask>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML doesn't support referencing other elements or values.

Therefore it is not possible what you want to achieve. If you want to create a solution like this, you have to incorporate that in the software you use to read this file and interpret it. You could come with an own syntax for it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yeah even I thought the same so I hacked it and created a small shell script inside the xml file to store and call the variable later.

Comment: You are welcome. Since you are new, please don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful to you.